# physical meaning of heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, biology, chemistry

consider the heat equation

$u_t=a(t)u_{xx}+f(x,t)$, $0<x<L$, $0<t<T$

subject to the initial condition

$u(x,0)=g(x)$

and boundary conditions

$u(1,t)=0,$ $u_x(0,t)+hu(0,t)=0$

where the functions $f,g$ and the constant$h$ is known.
My question is about meaning of this model in diverse scientific field. Such as in physics, chemistry, biology etc. can you give me some example about what it models in these area ? What does the boundary conditions model? and Is there any relationship between $a(t)$ and $h$?

Please help me about this problem. I really wonder the answers of these questions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Go ask a physicist!

Comment: As the name suggests, it describes how heat spreads in a body ...

Answer (score 1):

For example, it can model a process of heating a rod with time-depending heat conductivity coefficient (it can either rise or decay), for example, there is a chemical reaction in a rod, and a material (consequently, conductivity coefficient) changes with time. The boundary condition tells us that on one side of rod the temperature is constant, and on another a heat flow is constant (you might have made a mistake in a text, because in this moment your problem is ill-posed), which says us, for example, that there is a constant heat exchange with something. Here $a$ and $h$ can be both dependent and independent, because $a $ is a characteristic of rod, and $h$ is a characteristic of media, in which this rod is situated

Comment: @ cool you are right the other boundary condition should be $u(1,t)=0$

Comment: @ cool Thanks for answering my question. Can you explain the corrected boundary conditions. at the boundary $x=1$ it says temperature is constant but at $x=0$ what does it say? and can you give a specific example of dependence of $a$ and $h$ and independence of $a,h$. Please

Comment: At the second boundary the flow is constant, i.e. the heat per unit of time. Considering $a$ and $h$ -- honestly, they are always dependent, you choose by yourself what model to use, when the dependence is great, you should use a dependent case, otherwise independent case. I can't give a good example right now